# I can't install ffmpeg-php using cpanel

Tags: php

Dear all it might be a very dumb thing to ask for many of you. I am newbie in the web development. Spare me if its very simple. 
I need to take out thumbnails from the videos that I upload using ffmpeg. I have only access to cpenel. Most of the links that I have explored explains how to install ffmpeg on linux server. Neither I  know how to access linux server nor where and how can I install ffmpeg using cpanel. 
Thankyou so much for your time and consideration. 
Regards,
Mubeen

Comment: Can you install additional software on the server? What type of hosting do you have?

Comment: you'll have to ask the hosting support people if they will install it for you. cPanel only gives you fairly basic access to configure things directly related to your web hosting. They may well refuse to do this because of the likely performance impact of doing video processing, especially if it's a shared host.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you so much. You cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was confused if I could install ffmpeg using Cpanel. Bundle of thanks to @ADyson who answered it really well. I need to contact my hosting support to request them to install ffmpeg for me. I have a dedicated hosting. I might be charged more to have this functionality added.